# What is the Java timezone name for Atlanta Georgia? or any location?

Tags: java, timezone, jodatime

Our database keeps track of a number of "Production Facilities".  Each facility has an address, name, and most importantly timezone.  How do I figure out the name of a timezone?

It was obvious for our initial facilities because the code is named after our city (America/Edmonton).  How can I more generally determine the correct timezone code to use in Java via the call *DateTimeZone.forID("timeZone") ex DateTimeZone.forID("America/Edmonton")?*

Specifically we are opening a facility in Atlanta Georgia and I am unsure which code to use?  Is it one of these?

1. "Atlantic/South_Georgia"
2. US/Eastern"
3. "EST5EDT"
4. "EST"

Comment: "Atlantic/South_Georgia" refers to the islands near Antarctica in the South Atlantic

Answer (score 1):

The [IANA standard timezone identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IANA_time_zone_database) for Eastern Time is [`America/New_York`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/New_York). Presumably this is the standard Joda time is using, since (1) everyone uses it and (2) the city-name-as-identifier gives it away.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of information can be really tricky (not to mention tricky to keep current).  It can actually vary county by county (there is an excellent [West Wing scene about this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-J1NHzQ1sgc) :).  Google Maps API recently included support to go from [lat+lon to TimeZone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list with:

```
for (String string : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.getTimeZone(
    "GMT-05:00").getRawOffset())) {
System.out.println(string);
}
```

And it will include (among many others) "US/Eastern".

Answer (score 0):

You can list the available timezone id's using this method:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getAvailableIDs()

The time zone data seems to come from this database:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

You can do lookups in it here:
http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/xtra/tzdatepick.html